# How to build area (or prevent error) from invalid linestrings

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

I am playing with OpenStreetMaps data. Loaded by Osmosis into Postgres 9.4 with Postgis 2.2., with linestrings geometries built for `ways` table.

I want to make polygons from certain `relations` (in OSM, relation is group of ways (linestrings) - some marked as outer and some as inner, not every way have to be closed - multiple ways together can represent outer ring). But OSM data are not perfect - there are badly formed relations, where inner "holes" intersect outer ring. For example: http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/6095901#map=17/48.93209/19.14858

I am trying this query

```
SELECT ST_BuildArea(ST_Collect(w.linestring)) AS geom
FROM relations r
JOIN relation_members rm ON r.id = rm.relation_id AND rm.member_type = 'W'
JOIN ways w ON w.id = rm.member_id
WHERE r.id = 6095901 -- in reality here is broad condition on relation
GROUP BY r.id
```

and the result is error:

```
ERROR:  LWGEOM_GEOS_buildArea: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 19.149718131981164 48.934732947538478 at 19.149718131981164 48.934732947538478
```

So, what are my options here? Ideally I would like to "fix this" somehow - maybe disregard problematic "holes", or "clip" them to outer ring boundary etc.

If not possible, at least I would like the query to "skip" (return NULL geometry) for invalid relations like this and not die on first error with no results.

**EDIT**: The original example case was fixed in OSM data. Here is new example: relation ID 5636774 is self-intersecting multipolygon

Comment: You can use ST_MakeValid(geom) function for invalid geoms.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can avoid those errors by using `ST_Union` instead of `ST_Collect`. It is slower but it will get rid of overlapping sections. There are notes about it in the documentation for ST_Collect:

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html

Here is what I did to test out your second example:

```
create table ways ( id integer, linestring  geometry(Linestring, 4326) );
insert into ways values (1, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(52.3474437 35.3635293,52.347219 35.3636168,52.3472848 35.36407,52.3475095 35.3639826,52.3474437 35.3635293 )', 4326));
insert into ways values (1, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(52.3473579 35.3642849,52.347274 35.3636982,52.3468764 35.3638506,52.3468949 35.3639796, 52.3472102 35.3638587, 52.3472757 35.3643164, 52.3473579 35.3642849)', 4326));
insert into ways values (1, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(52.3468455 35.3636261, 52.34673 35.3636689, 52.3468697 35.3646806, 52.3474622 35.3644612, 52.3474339 35.3642567, 52.3473579 35.3642848, 52.3472762 35.3643151, 52.346957 35.3644333,  52.3468945 35.3639806,  52.3468765 35.3638507, 52.3468455 35.3636261)', 4326));
select ST_BuildArea(ST_Collect(linestring)) from ways;
select ST_BuildArea(ST_Union(linestring)) from ways;
```

I also considered using `ST_IsValid`, but it turns out `ST_IsValid(ST_Collect(linestring))` is true even for this bad shape, so I guess that doesn't help you.

Comment: I have tried ST_Union, and it is not good - any "holes" within polygon are lost this way - all the area inside outer shell is filled. This happens also in valid polygons, so this would produce much more invalid data than the few problematic invalid polygons